# Quantmod alternative for pandas?

Tags: python, software, opensource

I love quantmod package in R but now I am slowly moving towards python using pandas for my trading experiments. I have searched a lot for quantmod alternative for python but sofar I was unsuccessful. We can use pandas itself for downloading datas from the internet but its the other [small functions](http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/00Index.html) like **Cl,Ad,OpHi,ROC,Delt,dailyReturns** etc and technical indicators such as **EMA, RSI, MACD,SMI etc** I misses a lot. I have found these two packages for technical analysis [ta-lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) and [pandas_talib](https://github.com/femtotrader/pandas_talib) but both are not a good package for pandas. The former one strips the time series and we have to work with numpy array and the later has many bugs in it. Which library in python(with pandas) is the best alternative for quantmod in R.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at cufflinks and py-quantmod:

- https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks
- https://github.com/jackwluo/py-quantmod